# .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted) does not translate to SQL but .Where(i => i.IsDeleted.Equals(false)) does

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework 6 (Code First) and have some strange behaviour I do not want/like:
I have an entity class `Images` which has a boolean property `IsDeleted` and now I would like to get the first 25 images, which are not deleted, so I used the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Image> items = db.Images.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted).Take(25);
```

As this was very slow I investigated a little deeper and found out, that the `Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)` already triggers the DB query and all images are loaded (and parsed => slow) and the check then happens "in code". I then tried `Where(i => i.IsDeleted.Equals(false))` which worked fine and the check happend via SQL.

Why ist that so or how can I avoid this problem, as I like the first syntax much better?
Is this maybe a bug uf EF 6 beta or does this happen in al EF versions?

**UPDATE:**
The problem is the cast to `IEnumerable<Image>` (I did the `Where` not in the same line in my code, but changed it here for simplicity), but I am using this also to do a `.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` using `Func<T, TKey>`-keys and that does return `IOrderedEnumerable` and not `IOrderedQueryable`...

**UPDATE 2:**
Solved by using `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` keys...

Comment: Hrm. That's curious. What about Where(i => i.IsDeleted == false)?

Comment: @Tim: Same as `!i.IsDeleted`, but I think it may is my implicit cast to `IEnumerable<Image>` and not the `Where` (I did the `Equals` "inline", but the `!` "in the next line") - I am investigating...

Comment: @chrfin OK, so here is the reason. You'll get all items from database into memory when you do `IEnumerable<Image> items = db.Images;` Use `IQueryable` instead, to create query in couple lines and not make it execute until you really want it to.

Comment: @chrfin You could try adding `.AsEnumerable()` instead if casting.

Comment: What is the effect of `i => i.Deleted == false` ? Is `Deleted` nullable?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I think that is the problem - I now need to find out how to solve this for `OrderBy` as this returns `IOrderedEnumerable` which was the reason I changed it to `IEnumerable`...

Comment: @chrfin `OrderBy` returns `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, which inherits `IQueryable<T>`, so there should be no problem here.

Comment: @chrfin Actually `OrderBy` should return `IOrderedQueryable` when called on an `IQueryable` (which `DbSet` implements).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek sounds interesting, but why does it work with `Equals` but not with `!`? The problem seems also to be how the interpreter translate the `LINQ` to `SQL`?

Comment: @KingKing: I was wrong about that, as I did the `Equals` test before the `IEnumerable` cast and the `!` after...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Just saw that, but the `ThenBy` from my second order column does not...

Comment: If you solved it yourself either delete the question or post how you solved it as your own answer so other people can learn from you if they run in to the same problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I will do that as soon as I have it working, as I am still struggeling with some points ("Can't cast Int32 to TKey")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that as soon as you use `IEnumerable` the query will be executed and all the following queries will happen as LINQ to objects queries.

My mistake which let to this question was that I tested the queries the following way:

```
IEnumerable<Image> items = db.Images.Where(i => i.IsDeleted.Equals(false));
```

and

```
IEnumerable<Image> items = db.Images;
images = images.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted);
```

So in the first case the `Where` was still executed against an `IQueryable`, but in the second case against the `IEnumerable`.

Later on I faced a problem that for `OrderBy` and `IQueryable` you need `Expression<Func<T, K>>` parameters and I used `Expression<Func<T, IComperable>>`, but e.g. `Func<T, int>` can't be casted to `Func<T, IComperable>` by Entity Framework.
To see details how to overcome this problem see my other question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282427/orderbyfunct-icomperable-cant-be-translated-to-sql)