# OrderBy(Func<T, IComperable>) can't be translated to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I implemented a dynamic sorting logic (see [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29187/can-this-ordering-logic-be-done-better)) supplying `Expression<Func<T, IComperable>>` to the `OrderBy` method.

Now I have the problem, that EF can't convert the `IComperable` in the `Func<T, IComperable>` to its actualy type:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.IComparable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

at

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateAndAdjustCastTypes(TypeUsage toType, TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)

**Is there a way to solve this?**

The only way I found at the moment is "implementing" the `Func<>`'s as their real types, saving this type next to the `Func<>` and calling the `OrderBy` via reflection:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Type orderType, object expression)
{
    return typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "OrderBy")
       .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), orderType)
       .Invoke(null, new object[] { source, expression }) as IQueryable<T>
}
```

But that seems very ugly (and slow?) to me and is not really as nice to use as the current (sadly only for LINQ to objects working) solution...

**UPDATE:**
This problem seems to only occure when returning `int` or `bool` in the `Func<T, IComperable>`, as it works fine with `string`...

Comment: Add a second generic type parameter for the comparand.

Comment: @SLaks: You mean instead of the `Type orderType`? That does not work/help, as I do not know this at compile time and would only move the `MakeGenericMethod` "on level up". If you mean something different please explain...

Comment: Do you materialize your query before calling `OrderBy`? LINQ will try to convert your whole statement to SQL before materializing, so if you use a C# method as part of the query it wouldn't have any way to convert it to SQL.

Comment: Aren't you trying to reinvent the Dynamic Linq? Are there any reasons it doesn't work in your case?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: I do not want to use DLinq, because I like the strongly typed `Func<>`'s and also have some more complex ones like `i => (i.Revisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault() as CategoryRevision).Title` which supprisingly already work - it seems it only crashes when the type is `Int32` or `Boolean`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it the following way for now:

```
var orderDelegates = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();

Expression<Func<Image, int>> id = i => i.Id;
orderDelegates.Add(ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, id);
Expression<Func<Image, IComperable>> title = i => i.Title;
orderDelegates.Add(ContentItem.ORDER_BY_Title, title);
//more items...
```

(I would like this to be a little bit shorter - see [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29883/inline-conversion-cast-from-expressionfunct-int-to-lambdaexpression))

and in my own `OrderBy`:

```
var first = orderDelegates[orderKey ?? defaultKey];
Type firstType = first.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments()[1];

IOrderedQueryable<T> firstOrder;
if (firstType == typeof(int))
    firstOrder = items.OrderBy<T, int>(first, direction);
else if (firstType == typeof(bool))
    firstOrder = items.OrderBy<T, bool>(first, direction);
else
    firstOrder = items.OrderBy<T, IComparable>(first, direction);

var second = orderDelegates[defaultKey];
Type secondType = second.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments()[1];
if (secondType == typeof(int))
    return firstOrder.ThenBy<T, int>(second, direction);
else if (secondType == typeof(bool))
    return firstOrder.ThenBy<T, bool>(second, direction);
else
    return firstOrder.ThenBy<T, IComparable>(second, direction);
```

and

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T, K>(this IQueryable<T> items, LambdaExpression expression, OrderDirection? direction)
{
    if (direction == OrderDirection.Ascending || !direction.HasValue)
        return items.OrderBy(expression as Expression<Func<T, K>>);
    else
        return items.OrderByDescending(expression as Expression<Func<T, K>>);
}

public static IQueryable<T> ThenBy<T, K>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> items, LambdaExpression expression, OrderDirection? direction)
{
    if (direction == OrderDirection.Ascending || !direction.HasValue)
        return items.ThenBy(expression as Expression<Func<T, K>>);
    else
        return items.ThenByDescending(expression as Expression<Func<T, K>>);
}
```